# Batch learning general algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, montecarlo, reinforcement-learning

I have been reading the Reinforcement learning: An Introduction by Sutton and Barto (2012)
and I have come across the batch learning method. Unfortunately, this method is not very well described in the book 
and scientific articles regarding batch learning are yet too advanced for me.

Could anyone please elaborate on the method and provide exemplary pseudo-algorithm for this reinforcement learning method?

Comment: you better ask this at either stats.stackexchange.com or ai.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Thanks, I will do so. Should I delete this question here then?

Comment: not sure, but i guess you may leave it here